# How to select a pandas value from the next column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a csv file that looks like this when opened:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_csv("numbers.csv")
user_input = input()
print(table)
```

Output:

```
    year  number
0   2001   1
1   2002   41
2   2003   123
3   2004   135
```

Basically im trying to make it so when the user inputs matches the year it would return the number from the same row.

Ex:
user input = 2002
output = 41

No idea how to proceed any help is appreciated!

Comment: `df.loc[df['year']==user_input, 'number']`

Comment: @splash58 when im trying this user_input = input()

print(df.loc[df['annee']==user_input, 'taux']), i get an error :/

Comment: Don't forget that `input()` in python returns a string, which must be cast to `int` if your dataframe column type is numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_csv("numbers.csv")
user_input = int(input())
#print(table)

table.set_index('year', inplace=True)
print(table.loc[user_input]['number'])
```